# What to do when system locks up

Tags: 12.10, command-line, task-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Let's say the entire desktop freezes and nothing's responding... In Windows I'd just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> then find the application that's "Not Responding" and close it, or try ending processes until the system comes back to normal.

What would be the equivalent in Ubuntu? Is there a sort of task manager that can be used for this, or do I have to go through CLI for this? What would be the commands for doing what I mentioned earlier (listing and closing running apps+processes)?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/4408/44179